# under gluon project how to get the Android assets folder

Tags: gluon, javafxports, gluon-mobile

I had creat a gluon project ,then I put some folders and files under assets folder(Android)  and I want to read the files in application,now how do I can read the assets folder ? or how do I get the android Context or AssetManager ? under gluon project there is no Activity class or any class extends Activity.I had read all of the gluonMobile API, javaFXports API and developer docs, there is no help! 
Dose anyone can help me? I nearly got crazy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FXActivity` which you obtain via `FXActivity.getInstance` extends Activity, thus you can call `fxActivity.getAssets()` to get an instance of `AssetManager`