# How to get android contacts in a gluon application

Tags: android, android-contacts, gluon, javafxports

Is there any possibility to access the android contacts database from a gluon javafx application?

I was able to run some android specific code in this application but all documented examples for accessing contacts need an "Activity" context which I dont have.
(ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();....)
Do I really need an activity or can this implemented as a service?
(So far I had no success with the service context)

Comment: Hava a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416340/under-gluon-project-how-to-get-the-android-assets-folder

Comment: This answers my question completely.Thank you very much.